# Citation problem with natbib package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm using Springer Nature template in overleaf, but I keep getting citations in numbers and not author-year form.
Here's my code

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\setlength{\topmargin}{.1in} % head to top of body
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.5in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\marginparwidth}{-0.5in} \addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}




\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Mathematical Model}

\maketitle
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
Cancer is a health concern nowadays \citep{1}. 


\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And here is the .bib file:

```
@article{1,
author = {Sung, Hyuna and Ferlay, Jacques and Siegel, Rebecca and Laversanne, Mathieu and Soerjomataram, Isabelle and Jemal, Ahmedin and Bray, Freddie},
year = {2021},
month = {02},
pages = {},
title = {{Global cancer statistics 2020: GLOBOCAN estimates of incidence and mortality worldwide for 36 cancers in 185 countries}},
journal = {CA: a cancer journal for clinicians},
doi = {10.3322/caac.21660}
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please read the comments in that template example, which explain that the `Numbered` option to the class is what turns on the numeric citations. Removing that option will change to Author-Year style citations and references.

Comment: Inaddition to the issue identified by @DanMacKinnon, there's a second serious problem with your code: The instruction `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` tells `natbib` to generate numeric-style citation call-outs. Do please change this instruction to `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.

Comment: Thank you! saved my day.

Comment: Moreover, your code shouldn't feature a separate `\bibliographstyle` directive, as the document class option `sn-mathphys` implicitly specifies a different biblography style.